# Можно ли упростить создание поля?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Нужно сделать внешний ключ на эту же таблицу.

```
/*Новый столбец в стадии проектирования "доля стадии проектирования"*/
ALTER TABLE directories_object.design_stages ADD COLUMN id_ds BIGSERIAL;

COMMENT ON COLUMN directories_object.design_stages.id_ds
IS 'доля стадии проектирвания';

ALTER TABLE directories_object.design_stages ALTER COLUMN id_ds DROP NOT NULL;

UPDATE directories_object.design_stages SET
 "id_ds" = NULL;

/*Внешний ключ на эту же таблицу*/
ALTER TABLE directories_object.design_stages ADD CONSTRAINT design_stages_id_ds 
FOREIGN KEY (id_ds)
REFERENCES directories_object.design_stages(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

Получилось не очень: создать столбец - дропнуть ограничение - выставить NULL - создать внешний ключ.
А можно как нибудь упростить?

Comment: *создать столбец - дропнуть ограничение - выставить NULL* не используйте макроопределение типа - уложитесь в один шаг. *- создать внешний ключ* Один запрос может выполнять и несколько действий, их разделяют запятой.

Comment: а зачем вы объявляете поле bigserial когда вам очевидно нужен bigint? Сразу и set not null и update становятся не нужны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нечто вроде (с точностью до порядка параметров)

```
ALTER TABLE directories_object.design_stages 
ADD COLUMN id_ds 
    BIGINT UNSIGNED 
    NULL 
    DEFAULT NULL
    COMMENT 'доля стадии проектирования',
ADD CONSTRAINT design_stages_id_ds 
    FOREIGN KEY (id_ds)
    REFERENCES directories_object.design_stages(id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

Comment: Но без UNSIGNED (его вообще не нашел в postgresql) и COMMENT (отдельным запросом пустил)- на синтаксис ругается.

Comment: @Артём-.....-...-.- *COMMENT (отдельным запросом пустил)* нафига? просто ещё одно действие в этом запросе через запятую...

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COMMENT"
LINE 7:     COMMENT 'wegwewgew',

Comment: @Артём-.....-...-.- Ах да, постгресс же, у них COMMENT - это отдельная команда. Ну знач не судьба...